# How to crawl items from a list of links with Scrapy and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, hyperlink, web-crawler, scrapy

Can you help me please to correct this script: I have a list of links search results and I want to vist and crawl each one of these links.
But this script click just the first link and then my crawler stops.
Any help is appreciated
Code "Spider" :

```
    from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
    from scrapy import Selector
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
    from time import sleep
    import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
    from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
    from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse, TextResponse
    from extraction.items import ProduitItem
    from scrapy import log

    class RunnerSpider(CrawlSpider):
       name = 'products_d'
       allowed_domains = ['amazon.com']
       start_urls = ['http://www.amazon.com']

       def __init__(self):
           self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
       def parse(self, response):

         sel = Selector(response)
         self.driver.get(response.url)
         recherche = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="twotabsearchtextbox"]')
         recherche.send_keys("A")
         recherche.submit()

         resultat = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[@id="s-results-list-atf"]')
         #Links
         resultas = resultat.find_elements_by_xpath('//li/div[@class="s-item-container"]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a')
         links = []
         for lien in resultas:
            l = lien.get_attribute('href')
            links.append(l)
         for result in links:
           item = ProduitItem()
           link = result
           self.driver.get(link)
           item['URL'] = link
           item['Title'] = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h1[@id="aiv-content-title"]').text                     
           yield item

         self.driver.close()
```

Comment: Please first fix your code with your actual indents (or are these the actual indents of your code?), since Python cares about that, and human beings who read your code care about that. :)

Comment: Also, it seems you're still doing the things using `selenium.webdriver`, not `scrapy`. Seems you could have your task finished by using either one of them.

Comment: Ok, I edited my code @starrify

Answer (score 1):

So there are a few issues with your script.

1) Your `parse` function overrides CrawlSpider's implementation of the same function. That means that CrawlSpider's default behaviour, **which is in charge of extracting links from the page for continued crawling**, is not being called. That's not recommended when using CrawlSpider. See here for details:

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html

2) You don't yield any followup URLs yourself. You only yield Items. If you want Scrapy to keep processing URLs, you have to yield some form of Request object alongside your items.

3) You kill Selenium's driver at the end of the parse function. That will probably cause it to fail on a followup call anyway. There's no need to do that.

4) You're using Selenium & Scrapy's URL grabbing concurrently. That's not necessarily wrong, but keep in mind that it might result in some erratic behaviour.

5) Your script indentation is definitely off, that makes it difficult to look at your code.

Comment: OK, but you're still not yielding any Request objects. Either rename your parse function to some other name and assign it as the default request callback, or generate Requests yourself.